# How to get the current center tile in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to find out which is the currently centered tile in OpenLayers 3.

I can get the current position as latitude/longitude with `map.getView().getCenter()`, and the zoom level as `map.getView().getZoom()`.

Am I supposed to convert this to map tiles manually, or does OpenLayers 3 provide a functionality to easily calculate the correct tile x/y indices (the one in which the center lat/lon is located), or am I supposed to calculate this by myself?

Comment: Please clarify a little, do you want the tile for a given lat, lon and zoom ?

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Yes, that will do. If I can obtain the tile for `(lat,lon,zoom)`, I can obtain the center tile because I can already query the center lat/lon.

Comment: @nh2, are you working in lat/lon (4326) as a display projection and you want to find which spherical mercator (3857) tile is at the centre of your map view port?

Comment: @JohnBarça, that is very possible. I am working based on [this OpenLayers 3 example](https://github.com/nasa-gibs/gibs-web-examples/blob/release/openlayers3/js/geographic-epsg4326.js) from NASA that works on `EPSG4326`. I am not sure if `3857` is used at all though.

Comment: @nh2, no the wmts is in 4326 it would seem. So, based on something like this, http://jsfiddle.net/LJtEK/, you want to know which wmts tile corresponds to the center point of your map based on the getZoom and getCenter functions?

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the center position with

```
center =  ol.proj.transform(center, 'EPSG:900913', 'EPSG:4326');
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a ol3 tile source, you can get the [`TileGrid`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.tilegrid.TileGrid.html) by [`source.getTileGrid()`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Tile.html#getTileGrid).

Then use the [`getTileCoordForCoordAndResolution`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.tilegrid.TileGrid.html#getTileCoordForCoordAndResolution) method, to get the tile coordinates from a given map coordinate and resolution.